# Bayesian vs OLS . Degrees of freedom. do we need to bother about d.o.f for bayesian estimation?

Tags: bayesian, least-squares, degrees-of-freedom

Im new to bayesian and still trying to figure out the process in detail. I read somewhwere that one of the advantages of bayesian estimation is that it helps save on degrees of freedom and can be used when there are lesser number of data points and more number of parameters. Can someone through some light on this? i know its got something to do with MC MC but not very clear on how that helps.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to that "somewhere" for those who are struggling to understand exactly what it might have said?

Comment: Sorry i DOnt remember the exact page or article where i read it.. however i have come across a similar comment on the website..Im attaching the link below http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77939/mcmc-and-degree-of-freedoms-small-number-of-observations

Comment: Did you read the answer to that question? It points out (correctly) that the "stability" of the solution has nothing to do with MCMC: it is a result of the additional assumptions in the Bayesian calculation.  (MCMC is merely a computational method.)

Comment: yeah i did..it does say that too less data points while doing MLE leads to biased / unstable estimates, which equivalently in bayesian would mean that even if we were to perform the MCMC to find the estimates then they would be close to the prior( as too less data points gives more weightage to the prior )..What i want to clarify is where is the advantage in using bayesian? (The answer talks about the disadvantage whereas the question merely says its an advantage, but why?)